# How to create a simple company blog with a Tag-Cloud in Drupal-6?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, blogs, tag-cloud

I have to create a simple company blog within drupal-6. That means there should be only one single blog each user can post into.

What i have done so far is to create a custom content Type (blog) and a view that displays teasers of the recent blog entries with links to the full blog post.

Now i have to create a Tag-Cloud for this blog.
I created a taxonomy vocabulary for this "blog" content type and set the settings to Tags (Terms are created by users when submitting posts by typing a comma separated list.)
I also installed the Tagadelic Module and created a tag cloud with it, that works great and it displays all the Tags i entered when creating new blog entires.

But now to my problems:
First: If i click on an entry in this tag-cloud the default Taxonomy_term view is used to display the resulting blog entries. Thats bad because i would like to have it displayed the same way as in the view i already defined to show the blogs. Is there a way to use my view to display the results of the tag-cloud?

Second: On my view, below each blog-teaser should be a link to related blog entries (the ones that share the same terms). I do not have a clue how to do that.

is this even possible with the setting i have now or should i maybe take a whole other approach to create that company blog with tag clouds and related blog entries?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to solve both problems pretty easily, while keeping your current approach:

Take a look at your views list ('admin/build/views/list'). You should see a view called 'taxonomy_term (default)', which is usually disabled by default. This is an optional override of the built in taxonomy term page. You can enable this and configure it to look like the blog view you created.

Alternatively, you could leave that one disabled, but add another *display* of type 'page' to your already existing blog view, and configure that as an override to the built in taxonomy term. For this you'll need to set the path of that display to 'taxonomy/term/%' and adjust the display to use the term id argument as a filter (look at the above override for how this works).

You could also do it the other way round - use the default taxonomy_term override view, configure its output according to your blog view needs, and add another display for your recent blog entries to that. After this, delete your own blog view and use the new display of the taxonomy term override instead.